# Provide list of names for spark.csv method

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently trying to read a csv stored in S3. **The CSV does not contain header row**.

For spark 2.0.0 or greater,

I try reading it as :

```
df = spark.read.csv("path_to_csv")
```

Now this gives me columns name as :

```
_c0, _c1 , _c2 , ...
```

Is there a way by which I can provide the column names in the above function ? In **Pandas**, I can use argument `name=['col1','col2',...]`. Is something similar possible here ?

PS : My initial thoughts are to read it as CSV and then post process the column since [spark.read.csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) method does not seem to have any argument that would help here.

Comment: One post process solution I can think of is `new_df = df.toDF("col1","col2"..)`

Comment: Did you try something like:  df2 = df.withColumnRenamed("_c0", "NewName1").withColumnRenamed("_c1","NewName2")

Comment: @tbone Yes I tried and it works . The reason I did not prefer it is this would require calling this method for every column. To me this method seems more suitable for a single column change rather than full list. I am now trying to see if there is a feature request on github to provide the column names in the `read()` method directly.

Comment: Well, you'll have to define the mapping somewhere.  You can try creating a custom schema, but again, you'll be defining the list of column names.  How is the csv created?  (if you have control over it, you can try adding a header row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
 from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
```

you can create your own schema

```
schema = StructType([StructField("X", StringType(), True), StructField("Y", StringType(), True)])



df = spark.read.csv("path to csv",header=False,schema=schema)
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to let spark infer schema ?I tried it and it works but one needs to explicitly provide the data type for each column.

Comment: inferSchema='true' you can provide this in option.but it doesn't seem to infer the schema properly but you  can try